# Count down day 1 from each month

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a counter that count day 1 from each month and reset it self for next month when it reaches that specific day.

Here's my code:

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let currentDate = calendar.date(from: components)

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    // here we set the due date. When the timer is supposed to finish
    let competitionDate = NSDateComponents()

    competitionDate.year = components.year!
    competitionDate.month = components.month!

    competitionDate.day = 9
    competitionDate.hour = 00
    competitionDate.minute = 00
    let competitionDay = userCalendar.date(from: competitionDate as DateComponents)!

    //here we change the seconds to hours,minutes and days
    let CompetitionDayDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: Date().startOfMonth(), to: competitionDay)

    //finally, here we set the variable to our remaining time
    let daysLeft = CompetitionDayDifference.day
    let hoursLeft = CompetitionDayDifference.hour
    let minutesLeft = CompetitionDayDifference.minute

    print(daysLef)
    counter.value = CGFloat(daysLeft!)
```

The problem with this code is when it reaches day 0 it never reset it self back to count from current date to next month day # 9

Comment: If you're trying, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Calendar method `func nextDate(after date: Date, matching components: DateComponents, matchingPolicy: Calendar.MatchingPolicy, repeatedTimePolicy: Calendar.RepeatedTimePolicy = default, direction: Calendar.SearchDirection = default) -> Date?`, pass the day date component to it, use matchingPolicy `.strict`, repeatedTimePolicy `.first` and direction `.forward` to find the next date occurrence. Then you just need to use Calendar method `func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents` and pass the date components that you want returned (day, hour, minute):

```
extension Date {
    func timeLeftUntil(day: Int) -> (day: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int) {
        precondition(1...28 ~= day, "paycheck day \(day) is out of range 1...28")
        let nextDate = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: self, matching: DateComponents(day: day), matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .forward)!
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day,.hour,.minute], from: self, to: nextDate)
        return (dateComponents.day!, dateComponents.hour!, dateComponents.minute!)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
Date().timeLeftUntil(day: 25)  // (day 23, hour 0, minute 39)
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT  YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER

Comment: Hi Leo, Your code is working perfectly but I am facing a problem with the year. for example: let say timeLeftUntil(day: 10) if I change my calendar to be 12 of DEC my app freezes but if I change it the date to 2018 it works good. any suggestions?

Comment: I will test it here and let you know

Comment: What do you want to happen if the chosen day is 31 for example?

Comment: If you want to return the next 31st and doesn't matter if the current month has 31 days just use `.strict` matching policy

Comment: All I want is the code to count specific day day in each month. This day is supposed to be the day of the paycheck. So whenever the day reaches and turns to 0 it should resets it self to count another 30 days. I hope you get what I want.

Comment: So you will never set a day that doesn't exist in the month? Will it be always in the range from 1 to 28? If yes just use `.strict`

Comment: Ok. Thanks again 